# Importing HTML Table to Google Sheets with Multiple List Headers that Queries Table Data

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to import live NASCAR Race Results to Google Sheet.  I am open to an App Script or even trying to figure out the IMPORTXML, with XPath.  From my previous experience, IMPORTHTML will not work, but if someone knows of another way, let me know.

https://www.nascar.com/results/racecenter/2022/nascar-cup-series/...LATEST_RACE_NAME.../stn/live

For the IMPORTXML, I have the XPath of the element [@id="pgc-361475-1-0"]/div/div/div[7]/div[1] ... The problem is that the element changes by a table header that is selected (i.e., Qualifying, Practice 1, Practice 2, Entry, etc.) The default will return "Practice 1", but that is it, I can't get anything else to send an of the other live tables until after the race and it switches from Results to Recap.

I have also tried a Regex App Script see code below.  Again it will only send back the Practice 1 table.  I don't know how to reference or "Select" the other elements so that the right table will come back.  When the Race Starts, there is a Header Tab of "Race" I want to pull that tables position with Driver Name, Car No, and Position.

```
function myFunction() {

  clearRecords();

  var url = "https://www.nascar.com/results/racecenter/2022/nascar-cup-series/firekeepers-casino-400/stn/live";


  var str = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getContentText();


  const mainRegex = /<span class=\"race-center-driver-car-number\">([\s\S]*?)<\/span>/gi;
 
  var results = str.match(mainRegex);


  const driverPass1 = /(?<=<span class=\"race-center-driver-car-number\">).*?(?=<\/span>)/gi;


  for(var i = 0; i < 40; i++)
  {
    Logger.log('content: ' + results[i]);
    var driver1String = results[i].match(driverPass1);
    Logger.log('content: ' + driver1String[0]);


    addRecord(i+1, driver1String[0]);
  }
}

function clearRecords()
{
  var ss= SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var tableSheet = ss.getSheetByName("TABLE");
  tableSheet.getRange("A1:D40").clear();
}

function addRecord(count, driver, logo) {
  var ss= SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var tableSheet = ss.getSheetByName("TABLE");
  var currentRow = tableSheet.getLastRow();
  var nextRow = currentRow + 1;
  tableSheet.getRange(nextRow,1).setValue(count);
  tableSheet.getRange(nextRow,2).setValue(driver);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get data with

```
function getJSON(type='liveRaceURL') {
  const url = "https://www.nascar.com/results/racecenter/2022/nascar-cup-series/firekeepers-casino-400/stn/live"
  const source = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getContentText()
  const urls = JSON.parse(/raceCenterGlobals = ({.*?});/gms.exec(source)[1].replace(/'/g,'"'))
  console.log(UrlFetchApp.fetch(urls[type]).getContentText())
}
```

then parse the result

**type** could be one of these values:

> raceURL , pointsURL , liveRaceURL , stagePointsURL , snappyTVURL , keyMomentsURL , lapTimesURL , driverRecapURL , lapAveragesURL , lapFastURL , pitStopDataURL , liveFlagDataURL , scheduleFeedURL , weekendScheduleFeedURL

### application

in A1 : url

in A2 : type (define a data validation with `raceURL,pointsURL,liveRaceURL,stagePointsURL,snappyTVURL,keyMomentsURL,lapTimesURL,driverRecapURL,lapAveragesURL,lapFastURL,pitStopDataURL,liveFlagDataURL,scheduleFeedURL,weekendScheduleFeedURL`)

in A3 : `=getDataJSON(A1,A2)`

script :

```
function getDataJSON(url, type) {
  const source = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getContentText()
  const urls = JSON.parse(/raceCenterGlobals = ({.*?});/gms.exec(source)[1].replace(/'/g, '"'))
  let result = [];
  rec(JSON.parse(UrlFetchApp.fetch(urls[type]).getContentText()),'data')
  function rec(o, path) {
    for (let p in o) {
      let newPath = (/[^0-9]+/.test(p)) ? path + '.' + p : path + '[' + p + ']';
      if (o[p] != null) { if (typeof o[p] == 'object') { rec(o[p], newPath); } else { result.push([newPath, p, o[p]]) } }
    }
  }
  return (result)
}
```

[image]

Comment: happy to help solve the problem, you can now use query for example to extract what you expect from this exhaustive information

Comment: hi @mikesteelson   I am trying to do this again this year, however this code is not working on the first part.   ___Exception: Request failed for nascar.com returned code 403. Truncated server response: <!DOCTYPE html><html lang="en-US"><head><title>Just a moment...</title><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"><meta htt... (use muteHttpExceptions option to examine full response)___  Any ideas what has changed?

Answer (score 1):

You can get the raw data from the api urls. All the urls are in the source file. This will set you up together with [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k0su6345KDI)

See the data in your browser. Just put one of the `.json` urls in. With [this addon](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/json-viewer/gbmdgpbipfallnflgajpaliibnhdgobh) things will be formatted neatly.

```
function getLiveFeed(url) {

  //This is in the sourcecode of the website

  // var raceCenterGlobals = {
  //   'raceURL': 'https://cf.nascar.com/cacher/2022/1/5170/weekend-feed.json',
  //   'pointsURL': 'https://cf.nascar.com/live/feeds/series_1/5170/live_points.json',
  //   'liveRaceURL': 'https://cf.nascar.com/live/feeds/series_1/5170/live_feed.json',
  //   'stagePointsURL': 'https://cf.nascar.com/cacher/2022/1/5170/live-stage-points.json',
  //   'snappyTVURL': 'https://cf.nascar.com/cacher/2022/1/5170/snappytv.json',
  //   'keyMomentsURL': 'https://cf.nascar.com/cacher/2022/1/5170/lap-notes.json',
  //   'lapTimesURL': 'https://cf.nascar.com/cacher/2022/1/5170/lap-times.json',
  //   'driverRecapURL': 'https://cf.nascar.com/cacher/2022/1/5170/driver-recap.json',
  //   'lapAveragesURL': 'https://cf.nascar.com/cacher/2022/1/5170/lap-averages.json',
  //   'lapFastURL': 'https://cf.nascar.com/loopstats/prod/2022/1/5170.json',
  //   'pitStopDataURL': 'https://cf.nascar.com/cacher/live/series_1/5170/live-pit-data.json',
  //   'liveFlagDataURL': 'https://cf.nascar.com/live/feeds/live-flag-data.json',
  //   'scheduleFeedURL': 'https://cf.nascar.com/cacher/2022/race_list_basic.json',
  //   'weekendScheduleFeedURL': 'https://cf.nascar.com/cacher/2022/1/schedule-feed.json',
  //   'season': '2022',
  //   'raceId': '5170',
  //   'series': '1',
  //   'selTabName': 'live',
  //   'selSubTabName': ''
  // }

  const raceCenterGlobalsRequest = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url)
  const html = raceCenterGlobalsRequest.getContentText()
  const raceCenterString = /var raceCenterGlobals = {(.*?)};/gms.exec(html)[1]
  const raceCenterObject = raceCenterString.split(',').reduce((acc, curr) => {
    const [key, value] = curr.split("' :").map(e => e.replace(/'/g,"").trim())
    acc[key] = value
    return acc
  }, {})

  const liveFeedRequest = UrlFetchApp.fetch(raceCenterObject.liveRaceURL)
  const liveFeedData = JSON.parse(liveFeedRequest.getContentText())

  return liveFeedData

}

function testTheApi() {
  console.log(getLiveFeed("https://www.nascar.com/results/racecenter/2022/nascar-cup-series/firekeepers-casino-400/stn/live"))
}
```

Comment: Thank @RemcoE33,  I tried using the attached code, see the debugging error that I get.  Not sure what this telling me.

Comment: I can't seem to upload a screenshot, but I am getting an error in the following line '27'....  ```const raceCenterString = /var raceCenterGlobals = {(.*?)};/gms.exec(html)[1]```. Im using the liveRaceURL

Comment: It works fine for me: https://imgur.com/CvBPLtg.png But it gets you JSON with all data from the given url. It's up to you to parse the JSON into a table.

Comment: Do you mind showing the top part of the function?  I just want to make sure that I have everything setup properly.  When I debug, it shows under html all the data, but then gives me an error and says everything else is undefined.  I'm unsure what is wrong to fully execute.

Comment: 6:24:35 PM Error 
TypeError: Cannot read property '1' of null
getLiveFeed @ StackFlow.gs:29

Comment: Here is my sheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/17WnAb_siy5Nv5Wv19thmTUChjPvG42qf0dCba-CvFm0/edit?usp=sharing you can copy it and try to run the function `testTheApi()`